# Mono ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() throws an error

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I just got a VPS server running Linux Debian 7 and tried to get one of my C# servers running on it using Mono. Unfortunately it did not work the first time i ran it, it threw this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

I've found out the exact line which is causing this error and it is:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( myThread => TcpAccept() );
```

Without this line the server doesn't accept any connections and so on...

I would like to know how to fix this or find an alternative way to write this line. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The mono version is?

Comment: I typed in "mono --version" and got this

"Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-8+deb7u1)"

Comment: Can you try to upgrade to Mono 4? http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin It would be rather difficult to dig from Mono history to see when they started to support async compiler features, but it must come from a release like 3.* or 4.*.

Comment: Ok, I just updated to 4.0.1 version and now it's working fine! Thanks!